# How to add different variables to different stages in a deployment pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops

I have a traditional CI -> CD pipeline. In my deployment pipeline, I have 2 stages.
[image]

I would like to have JSON transform in each of them with different values in the same variables. The deployment pipeline allows me to set variables for the entire pipeline, not for the specific stage.

How can I set different values for variables in different stages?

Answer (score 0):

Set the variable scope as such:

[image: Variable scope demonstration image]